# weil der Begriff, ähnlich einer Markenbezeichnung, überall verstanden wird

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Here's the original text:

> Wie einzgartig die unterschiedlich gewürzten Fleischprodukte aus deutschen Landen sind, zeigt unter anderem die Tatsache, dass beispielsweise beim Wort "Bratwurst" in vielen Sprachen auf eine Übersetzung in die jeweilige Landessprache verzichtet wird, weil der Begriff, ***ähnlich einer Markenbezeichnung***, überall verstanden wird.

Why in the sentence above, the author used `einer`, and is it genitive or dative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ähnlich* here is a preposition that takes the dative. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aehnlich#Bedeutung-2

Comment: #2 - "Grammatik: in der Funktion einer Präposition mit Dativ"

Comment: The link you gave only lists *ähnlich* as an adjective, it only says it functions as a preposition. I gather that the dative comes from the related word *ähneln*, which is a dative verb. The cognate in English is "alike", which can't precede a noun at all. I think it's more usual to use *ähnlich wie* in this situation.